# How to restrict flash drives in Local Area Network

Tags: data-leakage, file-system, usb-drive

It is prohibited to use USB drives at our office, due to security reasons. But some people still use them to steal information. It is now a great risk factor at our office.

Now we need to ensure any one will not be able to use USB drive in our Local Area Network.

How can we ensure this?

Comment: steam information?

Comment: steal, sorry i edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are pieces of software that prevent you from using the usb ports like [Pointsec](http://www.checkpoint.com) except if you have a "trusted" usb device. In case some people still need USB drives.

But as many of us will agree, there is nothing better than to spray epoxy in your usb ports.

Comment: Which softwares ?

Comment: Pointsec can do this I think

Comment: Just contact a salesrep of them

Answer (score 7):

If the USB ports are not necessary, disable them in the BIOS (and password the BIOS), or simply epoxy over the USB sockets.

Some BIOSs will let you disable USB only for mass storage devices, which would seem to solve your problem. It's not a feature found on many boards, though.

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily done also using group policy by following the next steps from MSDN:

> Import this administrative template into Group Policy as a .adm file.
>   See the link in the More Information section if you are unsure how to
>   do this.   CLASS MACHINE CATEGORY !!category  CATEGORY !!categoryname 
>   POLICY !!policynameusb    KEYNAME
>   "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR"    EXPLAIN
>   !!explaintextusb
>        PART !!labeltextusb DROPDOWNLIST REQUIRED
>
> ```
>    VALUENAME "Start"
>    ITEMLIST
>     NAME !!Disabled VALUE NUMERIC 3 DEFAULT
>     NAME !!Enabled VALUE NUMERIC 4
>    END ITEMLIST
>  END PART    END POLICY   POLICY !!policynamecd    KEYNAME "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Cdrom"    EXPLAIN !!explaintextcd
>  PART !!labeltextcd DROPDOWNLIST REQUIRED
>
>    VALUENAME "Start"
>    ITEMLIST
>     NAME !!Disabled VALUE NUMERIC 1 DEFAULT
>     NAME !!Enabled VALUE NUMERIC 4
>    END ITEMLIST
>  END PART    END POLICY   POLICY !!policynameflpy    KEYNAME "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Flpydisk"    EXPLAIN
> ```
>
> !!explaintextflpy
>        PART !!labeltextflpy DROPDOWNLIST REQUIRED
>
> ```
>    VALUENAME "Start"
>    ITEMLIST
>     NAME !!Disabled VALUE NUMERIC 3 DEFAULT
>     NAME !!Enabled VALUE NUMERIC 4
>    END ITEMLIST
>  END PART    END POLICY   POLICY !!policynamels120    KEYNAME "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Sfloppy"    EXPLAIN
> ```
>
> !!explaintextls120
>        PART !!labeltextls120 DROPDOWNLIST REQUIRED
>
> ```
>    VALUENAME "Start"
>    ITEMLIST
>     NAME !!Disabled VALUE NUMERIC 3 DEFAULT
>     NAME !!Enabled VALUE NUMERIC 4
>    END ITEMLIST
>  END PART    END POLICY  END CATEGORY END CATEGORY   [strings] category="Custom Policy Settings" categoryname="Restrict Drives"
> ```
>
> policynameusb="Disable USB" policynamecd="Disable CD-ROM"
>   policynameflpy="Disable Floppy" policynamels120="Disable High Capacity
>   Floppy" explaintextusb="Disables the computers USB ports by disabling
>   the usbstor.sys driver" explaintextcd="Disables the computers CD-ROM
>   Drive by disabling the cdrom.sys driver" explaintextflpy="Disables the
>   computers Floppy Drive by disabling the flpydisk.sys driver"
>   explaintextls120="Disables the computers High Capacity Floppy Drive by
>   disabling the sfloppy.sys driver" labeltextusb="Disable USB Ports"
>   labeltextcd="Disable CD-ROM Drive" labeltextflpy="Disable Floppy
>   Drive" labeltextls120="Disable High Capacity Floppy Drive"
>   Enabled="Enabled" Disabled="Disabled"

For more information check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555324

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to consider process as well. For example, have you clearly communicated to everyone that USB sticks are banned in your Information Security policy?

Are you firing people found with one in their possession? (And if you haven't found one, are HR and Legal on board with firing anyone found in the future?)

Answer (score 1):

I have try many hardware and software solutions of USB cotrol (I'm sysadmin). At this time I use and can recommend NetRCM. It can lock access to USB devices in a network and a lot of other features. Here is it: http://teseisoft.com/products/netrcm